# How to get unique data from one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I had the following column:

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|1500  | 
|1500  |
|1600  |
|1700  |
|1700  |
|1700  |
|1800  | 
+------+
```

My question is I want to display only the ids that shown in column once, how it can be done?

So the result will be 1600 & 1800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID 
Having Count(*) = 1
```

Try the above

Answer (score 0):

```
select id  from tablename
group by id
Having Count(id) = 1
```